# A question about the orders of the elements of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $m$ and $n$ be to positive integers strictly larger than $1$. Is it possible to find a group $G$ in which there are two elements, say $a$ and $b$, such that the order of $a$ is $m$, the order of $b$ is $n$ and their product has infinite order?

If $m$ and $n$ are not coprime I think I have solved using a restricted wreath product (which is then directly summed to some cyclic group); but in the general case I could not achieve anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already talk of wreath product then I think you're ready for the following: in the free product of *any* two non-trivial groups, the product $\;ab\;$ , when each letter belongs to a different free factor, always has infinite order.

For example, if $\;C_2=\langle \,a\,\rangle\; \;,\;\;C=\langle\, b\,\rangle\;$, then in $\;C_2*C_3\;$ we have that $\;ord(a)=2\;,\;\;ord(b)=3\;$ , but certainly $\;ord(ab)=\infty\;$ .

Comment: You're right! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could just give the presentation: $\langle a,b|a^n=b^m=e \rangle$
A word that is equivalent to the zero word satisfies each of its $a$-blocks is a multiple of $m$ and each of its $b$ blocks is a multiple of $n$. but the first block of $a$'s of a word of the form $(ab)^n$ does not have a multiple of $m$ quantity of $a$'s. Then $(ab)^n$ is never the zero word.

Comment: This is just a generalization of my example: the free product of two cyclic groups of order $\;n\,,\,\,m\,$ resp.

Comment: I don't know what free product of groups is, the idea behind the presentation is you take the free group on the number of generators you have and then add some restrictions.

Comment: Exactly that. Pretty interesting construction.

Comment: But how would you prove that $ab$ has infinite order  in this group without yusing the theory of free products?

Comment: I just meant that you don't need to know what the free product of groups is. You need to know what a free group is, but not free products.

Comment: But you haven't proved that $ab$ has infinite order, so you haven't answered the question.

Comment: I changed it, what do you think?

Comment: The second sentence is just an statement without any justification.